# Синтаксический разбор предложения

Tags: синтаксис

"Дальний берег, освежённый и омытый грозой, рисовался в прозрачном воздухе. Всюду смеялась жизнь, проснувшаяся после бурной ночи".

Answer (score 2):

*Дальний берег, освежённый и омытый грозой, рисовался в прозрачном воздухе. Всюду смеялась жизнь, проснувшаяся после бурной ночи*.

*Дальний* — определение. *Берег* — подлежащее.  *Освежённый и омытый грозой* — обособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом. *Рисовался* — сказуемое. *В воздухе* — обстоятельство. *Прозрачном* — определение.
*Всюду* — обстоятельство. *Смеялась* — сказуемое. Жизнь — подлежащее. *Проснувшаяся после бурной ночи* — обособленное определение, выраженное причастным оборотом.

Answer (score 1):

decl!
При синтаксическом разборе нужна еще и характеристика предложения: повествовательное, невосклицательное, простое, двусоставное, распространенное, полное, осложнено обособленным распространенным согласованным определением, выраженным причастным оборотом.

P.S.  Я на форуме первый вечер, мне нравится, что такой форум есть. Но удивляет, что здесь не принято здороваться, обращаться друг к другу, благодарить. Давайте будем соблюдать минимальные правила речевого этикета. Ведь все-таки это форум (я так понимаю,  на форумах общаются), а не справочник по русскому языку в электронном варианте.

Answer (score 0):

*Берег* — подлежащее
*рисовался* — сказуемое
*Дальний, освежённый и омытый грозой, прозрачном* — определение
*в воздухе* — обстоятельство места.
*Жизнь* — подлежащее
*смеялась* — сказуемое
*всюду* — обстоятельство
*проснувшаяся после бурной ночи* — определение.